# Concerns when using ScriptManager for Custom Non-Ajax Scripts

Tags: asp.net, scriptmanager

I have an application that uses various script files.  These files are not used for any AJAX purposes.  However, I am using MS AJAX Libraries.  My goal is to use the ScriptManager to manage release and debug versions of my JavaScript.  Is this the right approach?  Is there a better way to handle this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there is some additional overhead when you are using the ScriptManager.  After doing some reading it looks like the ScriptManager control should only be used if you plan on sending down the AJAX library otherwise it would be advised to use the ClientScriptManager.